# Awkward positioning of light switches

Tags: lighting

In my home we have a few light switches that don't make much sense. 
Some are backwards which is easy to remedy, but others seem to be in stupid locations.

An example would be that the switch for a light at the top of the sitars is on a separate wall to the one for the downstairs.

Is there an easy and simple way to resolve this?

Comment: >Is there an easy and simple way to resolve this?

That depends entirely on the way it is wired. We will need a lot more information. A good drawing and some pictures would help.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't have access to any information other than the location of the switches and lights. I'm clueless here, so i was hoping it was some sort of circuit passing through them all,

Comment: How can a switch be backwards?  Also, since we can't see how your house is laid out, or where the switches are. It's not possible for anybody to provide an accurate answer.  You might be able to install wireless switches, but there's no way to know for sure based on the information you've provided.

Comment: By. "backwards", do ou mean upside down? If so, it's easy to reinstall them right side up... unless they're part of a two-way swich, in which case you have to choose between have the switches agree to turn or having them be different to turn on;. If you really hate switch locations, you can have an electrician relocate them and repair ir cover the old box, or you can install a remote-controllable switch and just put a battery-powered remote in the place you want the switch to be.

Comment: I'd all but guaranty the ones you consider "backwards" are 3-ways.  3-way switches do NOT have an on or off position. A 3-way can be either on or off in either position.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and simple? No.

They were designed and installed in inconvenient locations. The only way to fix this would be to move the switches and their wiring to wherever it is that you'd like them to go to. This would involve cutting walls, rewiring, patching the walls, and refinishing the walls. It's not as simple as just putting a blank cover over the old device; you'd still have to pull new wires to the new switch from your light(s) and power.

However, if you're fine having the switch where it's at, but would like some more functionality, you'd want to install a 'smart' switch.. either to be controlled through wifi or through a remote. Or even, depending on it's usage, you could get a motion sensing switch to automatically flip on when it detects someone. This route is almost as expensive as just rewiring though.

I'm in the same place right now. We just bought an old house that has a garage in the back, but all of the light switches are wired as if one would enter through the front door, no three-ways. So every room you enter, you have to walk to the other end of it to flip a light on. Oh, and there's no light in our staircase, which isn't too bad when the upstairs or downstairs hall light is on. But you can't cut the downstairs off from upstairs and the upstairs light switch is at the farthest end of the hall. Nothing to take away from the house, just a huge inconvenience. Smart switches will be the route for a couple rooms, but mainly I'm just using a lot of light sensing nightlights.

Good luck.